Can I make a VM image from an intel Mac and run it on an M3 one?
Can I build a VM image from an old Intel Mac and run that in parallels or VMware or whatever on a new M3 machine?

Old machine

MacBook Pro, mid 2014
macOS Mojave Version 10.14.6
2.2 GHz intel Core i7
16 GB RAM
250 GB SDD


New Machine

MacBook Air, 2024
macOS Sonoma 14.3
Apple M3
8 GB RAM
250 GB SDD



All I really need here is one program (Outlook; see below), I could delete everything else except the OS and Outlook to make the image smaller. But is it possible to virtualize an intel Mac onto an M3 one? If so, how? And what virtualization tool should I use? I found this post that mentions something called UTM, is that my only choice?
Finally, given the context below, is there a simpler way here? All I really want to do is duplicate her email setup but it is too large to be imported.

More context, to avoid an XY problem
I am helping my septuagenarian mother migrate from her old MacBook Pro to her new MacBook Air. This has mostly worked surprisingly well using macOS's migration assistant, however, the one sticking block is her email program. She was using Outlook 2011 on the old machine, and has Outlook 2021 on the new one. Migration failed because the old one was 32bit and the new one is 64 (as far as I can tell, that was the reason).
I tried to export her emails to an .oml file, but I can't import them because the file is too large and there isn't enough space on disk. Or so I think. When I try to import, I select the option to import .oml, then select the file, and click on Continue, and get taken back to the file selection dialogue. It is only when I cancel the process that I get a message telling me I need 60GB free and I should check my disk. A similar situation is described here.
After reading various blog posts (I don't know macs, I've been a Linux user for the past quarter century) I learned that macOS has some clever features that use up disk space, but it looks like Outlook doesn't play nice with them and actually needs to see free space. So I disabled macOS snapshots by setting them to "manual" and that did let me regain a bit more disk space, but still not enough to import the entire 40GB .oml file I created.
I am trying various workarounds, but there are some constraints:

She has her emails organized into local folders, and keeping this folder structure is essential.
This is a POP account, so there are no IMAP folders on the server.
Setting up a new IMAP account does bring in several emails, but the folder structure is lost.
Outlook only allows me to export everything or a specific "category", but not folders.

The best I have come up with so far is to place all emails of the past 4 years in a category, export those, and then import this far smaller collection to the new Outlook. I am hoping a VM might solve my issues.

Naturally, as soon as I posted this, I went back and tried to import the huge 40G file and today it worked. Yesterday it didn't, but today it does. I can only assume snapshots have aged away, freeing more disk space! I am still interested in whether I could virtualze the old machine on the new one though, even if I am now unlikely to use it. Feel free to close if this makes the question too theoretical.

It wouldn't be a VM.  Different CPU architectures.  You might be able to get something like QEMU to run it under emulation.  I AM surprised that Migration Assistant didn’t move things over?

@MarcWilson it did move outlook over, but its icon was crossed out in what I read indicates it is a 32bit binary on a 64bit system. I. Imagine it would have worked, otherwise.

Vmware Fusion oddly does not support any macOS VM's on Apple Silicon ARM hosts. On Intel Macs they supported macOS client VMs and it was legal under Apple licensing terms. Now VMWare hilariously says it's "not in scope."
UTM is based on QEMU and does either virtualization (same CPU architecture) or emulation (different CPU). I've only setup macOS as ARM on ARM. The same basic question was asked in 2021. It might be possible, but probably not worth the hassle.

Apple says you can virtualize macOS only on Apple hardware.  They don't specify the hypervisor you have to use.
